# Tangent with Geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A spiral water-slide has $40\, m$ of track and a constant slope $\alpha$ of $tan = 0,2$.
Find the height.

I tried $ 0,2=\frac{x}{\sqrt{40^{2}-x^{2}}}$ and $0,2=\frac{\sqrt{40^2-y^2}}{y}$

Comment: What are the assumptions of your trials?

Comment: I drew an circular spiral and set the parameters as a right circular cylinder.

Comment: Does a right circular cylinder have a slope? What parameter of the cylinder do you denote as $x$ and which one was set to 40m?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I made a mistake. I set the radius as the y and the x as the height and 40 m as the hypotenuse. So I set the angle between y and the hypotenuse as the tangent. Solving with Pythagoras I isolated y and then since tan is equal to x divide by y I replaced and solve.

Answer (score 0):

If one assumes that $x$ in your first equation stays for the height of the slide, then the equation is correct. The second equation (for $y$) is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for trying help me. I tried that way but I got $\frac{20\sqrt{26}}{13}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{40^2 \cdot 0,04}{1,04}}$ However the answer is  $\sqrt{26}$

Comment: Is there any figure which shows the "spiral water-slide". What is meant by the "track" - the length?

Comment: There is no figure, just the question text. Yes where is track is the length of the spiral water-slide. And I also tried assume this length is the circumference length of the circular cylinder.